# ¿Como extraer filas de un dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

me encuentro con el siguiente problema, necesito extraer por filas los datos de un dataframe, es decir crear una lista de listas por cada fila, como en el ejemplo

```
>>df
    P01          P02         P03        P04         P05          P06         P07                
 0.143335     0.003217    0.238816    0.181586    0.085305     0.029136   0.040685       
 0.246245     0.059063    0.031106    0.017317    0.045353     0.214421   0.127492   
 0.038312     0.006075    0.072793    0.044644    0.016160     0.003624   0.010822    
 0.162723     0.087614    0.049509    0.229241    0.108593     0.012520   0.246437
```

he logrado dividir en filas utilizando indices

```
f1=list(df.iloc[1,:])
f2=list(df.iloc[2,:])
f3=list(df.iloc[3,:])
f4=list(df.iloc[4,:])
```

y luego unirlas asi

```
df3=f1,f2,f3,f4
```

con esto obtengo el resultado deseado

```
([0.143335, 0.003217, 0.238816, 0.181586, 0.085305, 0.029136, 0.040685],
 [0.246245, 0.059063, 0.031106, 0.017317, 0.045353, 0.214421, 0.127492],
 [0.038312, 0.006075, 0.072793, 0.044644, 0.01616, 0.003624, 0.010822],
 [0.162723, 0.087614, 0.049509, 0.229241, 0.108593, 0.01252, 0.246437])
```

​
mi problema esque necesito realizar esta accion para una gran cantidad de datos, me gustaria poder realizarlo de forma automatica, es decir, para la cantidad de filas que existan pueden ser 4 o pueden ser mas.

AYUDA!! PORFAVOR

Comment: Esta pagina (en ingles) responde a tu pregunta? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-pandas-dataframe-into-a-list/

Comment: Mi forma favorita es el metodo 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes iterar de esta forma:

```
lista = [] #lista vacia para llenarla con datos
for i in range(len(df)):
    lista.append(list(df.iloc[i,:]))
```

y obtienes la lista con los datos.

Comment: Hola npho111, parece que tu respuesta sirvió para resolver el problema, pero ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Sería ideal si pudieras editar la respuesta para añadir una breve descripción de lo que hace o cómo resuelve el problema. Lee [answer] para más información.